# Local cohomology and primary decomposition

Tags: commutative-algebra, local-cohomology

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I$ an ideal and $M$ a finite
>   $R$-module. Let $0=N_1\cap \dots \cap N_s$ in $M$ be a primary
>   decomposition with $N_i$ $p_i$-primary submodules of $M$. Show that
>   $\Gamma_I(M)=\bigcap\limits_{I\not\subset p_i} N_i$.

**Proof:** Let $0=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^s N_i$. By HW 7.1a,
$$
\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \left(0\underset{R}{:}I^n\right)
= 0^{(I^n)} 
= \bigcap\limits_{I^n\not\in p_i} N_i
$$

And now I am stuck.

I know that I need to use this fact:

> **Fact 1:** Show that $\Gamma_I(M)=0$ if and only if $I$ contains a non
>   zerodivisor on $M$.

but I don't know how. Also for reference purposes: HW 7.1a is

> **Fact 2:** Let $R$ be Noetherian ring and $I, J$ $R$-ideals. Write $I^{\langle J\rangle}=\bigcup\limits_{n\geq 1} (I:J^n)$, which is called the
>   *saturation* of $I$ with respect to $J$. Show
>
> a. If $I=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^m q_i$ with $p_i$-primary, then
>       $I^{\langle J \rangle}=\bigcap\limits_{J \not\subset p_i} q_i$.
>
> b. $I^{\langle J \rangle}$ is the unique largest $R$-ideal that
>       coincides with $I$ locally on the open set $\mathrm{Spec}(R)\setminus V(J)$.

Comment: The idea is the following: $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}(0:_MI^n)=\bigcup_{n\ge 1}(N_1\cap\cdots\cap N_s:_MI^n)=\bigcap_{i=1}^s\bigcup_{n\ge1}(N_i:_MI^n)$, so you have to figure out what is $\bigcup_{n\ge1}(N_i:_MI^n)$. Now consider two cases: $I\subseteq p_i$ or not. In the first case you get $M$, while in the second you get $N_i$.

Comment: So when am I using the first fact? The question is given with part a and b and I would really like to use that fact with the nonzero

Comment: When prove the second case from my hint you show that $I$ contains a non-zerodivisor on $M/N_i$, and then $\Gamma_I(M/N_i)=0$. This also means that $\bigcup_{n\ge1}(N_i:_MI^n)=N_i$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the assist